# How do you create a fully-fledged Python package?

Tags: python, package, packaging

When creating a Python package, you can simply write the code, build the package, and share it on PyPI. But how do you do that?

1. How do you create a Python package?
2. How do you publish it?

And then, what if you want to go further?

3. How do you set up CI/CD for it?
4. How do you test it and check code coverage?
5. How do you lint it?
6. How do you automate everything you can?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Preamble

When you've published dozens of packages, you know how to answer these questions in ways that suit your workflow(s) and taste. But answering these questions for the first time can be quite difficult, time consuming, and frustrating!

That's why I spent days researching ways of doing these things, which I then published as a blog article called [How to create a Python package in 2022](https://mathspp.com/blog/how-to-create-a-python-package-in-2022).

That article, and this answer, document my findings for when I wanted to publish my package [extendedjson](https://github.com/mathspp/extendedjson)

## Overview

Here is an overview of some tools you can use and the steps you can take, in the order I followed them while discovering all of this.

Disclaimer: other alternative tools exist (usually) & most of the steps here are not mandatory.

- Use [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for dependency management
- Use [GitHub](https://github.com/) to host the code
- Use [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) to ensure committed code is linted & formatted well
- Use [Test PyPI](https://test.pypi.org/) to test uploading your package (which will make it installable with `pip`)
- Use [Scriv](https://scriv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for changelog management
- Upload to the real [PyPI](https://pypi.org)
- Use [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/) to test your Python code
- Use [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/) to automate linting, formatting, and testing across Python versions

  - [black](https://github.com/psf/black)
  - [isort](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/)
  - [pylint](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/)
  - [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) with [mccabe](https://github.com/PyCQA/mccabe)
- Add code coverage with [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/)
- Set up CI/CD with GitHub Actions

  - run linters and tests
  - trigger automatically on pull requests and commits
  - integrate with [Codecov](https://about.codecov.io/) for coverage reports
  - publish to PyPI automatically
- Add cool README badges
- Tidy up a bit

  - set tox to use pre-commit
  - remove duplicate work between tox and pre-commit hooks
  - remove some redundancy in CI/CD

## Steps

Here is an overview of the things you can do and more or less how to do it. Again, thorough instructions plus the rationale of why I picked certain tools, methods, etc, can be found in [the reference article](https://mathspp.com/blog/how-to-create-a-python-package-in-2022).

- Use [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for dependency management.

  - `poetry init` initialises a project in a directory or `poetry new dirname` creates a new directory structure for you
  - do `poetry install` to install all your dependencies
  - `poetry add packagename` can be used to add `packagename` as a dependency, use `-D` if it's a development dependency (i.e., you need it while developing the package, but the package users won't need it. For example, `black` is a nice example of a development dependency)
- Set up a repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/) to host your code.
- Set up pre-commit hooks to ensure your code is always properly formatted and it passes linting. This goes on `.pre-commit-config.yaml`. E.g., the YAML below checks TOML and YAML files, ensures all files end with a newline, makes sure the end-of-line marker is consistent across all files, and then runs [black](https://github.com/psf/black) and [isort](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/) on your code.

```yaml
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.0.1
    hooks:
      - id: check-toml
      - id: check-yaml
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: mixed-line-ending
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.3.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
  - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort
    rev: 5.10.1
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        args: ["--profile", "black"]
```

- Configure [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to use the [Test PyPI](https://test.pypi.org/) to make sure you can publish a package and it is downloadable & installable.

  - Tell [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) about Test PyPI with `poetry config repositories.testpypi https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`
  - Log in to Test PyPI, get an API token, and tell Poetry to use it with `poetry config http-basic.testpypi __token__ pypi-your-api-token-here` (the `__token__` is a literal and shouldn't be replaced, your token goes after that).
  - Build `poetry build` and upload your package `poetry publish -r testpypi`
- Manage your CHANGELOG with [Scriv](https://scriv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

  - run `scriv create` before any substantial commit and edit the file that pops up
  - run `scriv collect` before any release to collect all fragments into one changelog
- Configure Poetry to use [PyPI](https://pypi.org)

  - login to PyPI and get an API token
  - tell Poetry about it with `poetry config pypi-token.pypi pypi-your-token-here`
  - build & publish your package in one fell swoop with `poetry publish --build`
- Do a victory lap: try `pip install yourpackagename` to make sure everything is going great ;)
- Publish a GH release that matches what you uploaded to PyPI
- Write tests. There are *many* options out there. [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/) is simple, versatile, and not too verbose.

  - write tests in a directory `tests/`
  - start test files with `test_...`
  - actual tests are functions with a name starting with `test_...`
  - use assertions (`assert`) to check for things (tests fail when asserting something Falsy); notice sometimes you don't even need to import `pytest` in your test files; e.g.:

```py
# In tests/test_basic_example.py

def this_test_would_definitely_fail():
    assert 5 > 10

def this_test_would_definitely_pass():
    assert 5 > 0
```

- run tests with the command `pytest`
- Automate testing, linting, and formatting, with [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/).

  - tox creates virtual environments for separate Python versions and can run essentially what you tell it to. Configuration goes in `tox.ini`. You can also embed it in the file `pyproject.toml`, but as of writing this, that's only supported if you add a string that actually represents the `.ini` configuration, which is ugly. Example `tox.ini`:

```ini
[tox]
isolated_build = True
envlist = py38,py39,py310

[testenv]
deps =
    black
    pytest
commands =
    black --check extendedjson
    pytest .
```

The environments `py38` to `py310` are automatically understood by [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/) to represent different Python versions (you guess which ones). The header `[testenv]` defines configurations for all those environments that [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/) knows about. We install the dependencies listed in `deps = ...` and then run the commands listed in `commands = ...`.

- run tox with `tox` for all environments or `tox -e py39` to pick a specific environment
- Add code coverage with [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4.2/)

  - run tests and check coverage with `coverage run --source=yourpackage --branch -m pytest .`
  - create a nice HTML report with `coverage html`
  - add this to tox
- Create a GitHub action that runs linting and testing on commits and pull requests

  - GH Actions are just YAML files in `.github/workflows`
  - this example GH action runs tox on multiple Python versions

```yaml
# .github/workflows/build.yaml
name: Your amazing CI name

# Run automatically on...
on:
  push:  # pushes...
    branches: [ main ]  # to the main branch... and
  pull_request:  # on pull requests...
    branches: [ main ]  # against the main branch.

# What jobs does this workflow run?
jobs:
  build:  # There's a job called “build” which
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # runs on an Ubuntu machine
    strategy:
      matrix:  # that goes through
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]  # these Python versions.

    steps:  # The job “build” has multiple steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2  # Checkout the repository into the runner,

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2  # then set up Python,
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}  # with the version that is currently “selected”...

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |  # Then run these commands
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install tox tox-gh-actions  # install two dependencies...

      - name: Run tox
        run: tox  # and finally run tox.
```

Notice that, above, we installed tox **and** a plugin called `tox-gh-actions`.
This plugin will make tox aware of the Python version that is set up in the GH action runner, which will allow us to specify which environments tox will run in that case.
We just need to set a correspondence in the file `tox.ini`:

```ini
# tox.ini
# ...
[gh-actions]
python =
    3.8: py38
    3.9: py39
    3.10: py310
```

- Integrate with [Codecov](https://about.codecov.io/) for nice coverage reports in the pull requests.

  - log in to Codecov with GitHub and give permissions
  - add Codecov's action to the YAML from before **after** tox runs (it's tox that generates the local coverage report data) and add/change a coverage command to generate an `xml` report (it's a format that Codecov understands)

```yaml
# ...
      - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
        with:
            fail_ci_if_error: true
```

- Add a GH Action to publish to PyPI automatically

  - just set up a YAML file that does your manual steps of building and publishing with Poetry **when** a new release is made
  - create a PyPI token to be used by GitHub
  - add it as a secret in your repository
  - configure Poetry in the action to use that secret

```yaml
name: Publish to PyPI

on:
  release:
    types: [ published ]
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout and set up Python

      - name: Install poetry and dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install poetry

      - name: Configure poetry
        env:
          pypi_token: ${{ secrets.PyPI_TOKEN }}  # You set this manually as a secret in your repository
        run: poetry config pypi-token.pypi $pypi_token

      - name: Build and publish
        run: poetry publish --build
```

- Add cool badges to your README file like
  [image: PyPI version]
  [image: Build status]
  [image: Code coverage]
  [image: GitHub stars]
  [image: Support Python versions]
- Tidy up a bit

  - run linting through tox on pre-commit to deduplicate effort and run your preferred versions of the linters/formatters/...
  - separate linting/formatting from testing in tox as a separate environment
  - check coverage only once as a separate tox environment

Comment: In order to automate and reproduce the steps multiple times, I created a GitHub template. Do check it out @ https://github.com/a-parida12/poetry_pypi_template.